# Pycharm выполнение файла остановилось из-за перегрузки пк

Tags: python, pycharm

Написанный на Python обработчик текста регулярными выражениями у меня обрабатывает большие обьемы текста и что бы компьютер не простаивал я решил посмотреть видео и т.д.

Запустил `python file.py` в терминале, оно поработало час, спустя 10 минут открываю pycharm и тут смотрю - файл выработал не полностью, остановился вывод yield в терминале. Файл не обновляется и я могу только нажать ctrl+c и начать сначала, но это целый дополнительный час ожидания.

До этого также случалось такое, и не случалось только если я держал Pycharm открытым всё время выполнения файла

Предполагаю что случилось это из-за перегрузки ЦП(стоит в пк старый пентиум)

Собственно кто с таким встречался? В чём проблема? Можно ли возобновить действие программы с места окончания?

Comment: можно парсить файл построчно, и каждую строку вписывать в другой файл, тем самым создавая "чекпоинт", ну а дальше я думаю понятно

Comment: Не в этом проблема, программа выводит данные в файл, вывела уже несколько тысяч строк(за час) и ещё осталось немало

Comment: После этого программа выполнения в терминале остановилась. Не закончилась, а просто как будто залагала, её могу только остановить(ctrl c) но я не хочу тратить результат обработки файла в течении целого часа. Можно ли "разглагать терминал"?

Comment: нет, если терминал завис - то уже все, но я говорю, начните парсинг с уже пройденных строк - сэкономите час